# Подзагрузка данных ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста есть такой скрипт

```
 <script>
    // noty
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#c-fr-prcount').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "friends/notyfrnds.php?id=<?=$myrow2[id]?>",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
    $('#reqfrndscon').html('');
    },
    success: function(html){
    $("#reqfrndscon").html(html);
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
При клике идет загрузка контента, как сделать при повторном клике закрывался блок?Помогите пожалуйста.
```

Comment: о каком блоке идет речь? не могли бы вы привести пример html-кода, с которым работает этот код?

Comment: @vanchester вот скрипт прислал вот сам блок <div id="reqfrndscon"></div>. В этот блок при клике на ссылку подгружается заявки на добавления в друзья.вот мне нужно что бы при повторном нажатии на ссылку закрылось это окошоко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onload = function (){
    document.getElementById("c-fr-prcount").IsDown = false;
    document.getElementById("c-fr-prcount").onclick = function (){
        if(!this.IsDown){
            // Делаем ajax запрос
         } else {
            // Скрываем блок
           }
         this.IsDown = !this.IsDown;
    }

}
</script>
```

С JQuery не дружу, вот простой пример на чистом js